# Logcat not working on command prompt. It only works in eclipse IDE

Tags: android, logcat

So I can see Logcat working with no problems in my eclipse IDE. However, when I try to run it in a command prompt, i get a bunch of logcat data for about a second, and then the whole thing freezes.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: how are you calling it from the prompt?

Comment: "adb logcat" No filters no nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it.

I had two adb.exe files. One of them was in my WINDOWS directory, and the other was in my SDK tools directory. The eclipse IDE was using the version in my SDK tools directory. When I would use a command prompt to start adb, it would use the version in my WINDOWS directory. I deleted that version, and everything is working great now.

Thanks.

Comment: So you were probably seeing a message like: * * logcat daemon is out of date, restarting * *

Comment: Yes, I was seeing that now that you mention it. I thought that was because I had my eclipse IDE open though. Looks like I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That looks sort of how logcat works.

- First you see a backlog or history of the messages.
- Then it hangs, but **only** until some new event is received.

Comment: Right, but when I try to open apps up and do various things, I never see it update at all. Certainly no where to the degree that I can see Logcat update in the eclipse IDE.